# Interrogative form without the use of auxiliary verb (not about inflection or informal convo)

Tags: grammar, questions

I've looked up some threads before writing this and haven't found what I'm looking for. This is not about informality or oral use of the language.

Consider these two questions:

> What happened to him?
>
> Who killed your husband?

Are they correct or should they be:

> What did happen to him?
>
> Who did kill your husband?

From where I stand, the first example is gramatically correct. However, I can't see a subject (you, he, etc) nor the use of the auxiliary verb or modal verb.

Is this a different case for interrogative form or just oral communication messing with "formal" grammar?

Comment: Try with *has* / *had*. Good Luck.

Comment: The subjects in the sentences are *what* and *who* respectively. You can add *did* if you want—although it would normally be put in italics or otherwise stressed. (Saying those sentences without such stress would be unusual.)

Comment: In your examples, the subjects are "what" and "who", and no subject-auxiliary-inversion is required in such interrogatives. In the last two, the dummy auxiliary verb "do" is not being used for subject-auxiliary inversion, but to emphasise the positive polarity of the clause. Since the stress must be placed on an auxiliary verb, auxiliary "do" must be added here.